# Github doesn't let me change title of ssh key

Tags: github

I accidentally put a wrong title for ssh key. Is it possible to change it without having to delete and generate a new key? I was looking in the settings but couldn't find it on github.com.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear you can change the title, but you don't need to generate a new key. Just delete the key on Github and upload the same key again with the correct title.